# Callback like before_action in rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

example,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 def method1
   same_process
 end

 def method2
   same_process
 end

 def method3
   same_process
 end
 private
 def same_process
  #same process code
 end
end
```

As you all can guess, I want DRY!

I want to remove that same_process calling in each method.

If  this was `ActionController` base, there is an awesome callback,

```
before_action or before_filter
```

but this is `MODEL` :(

any good solution?

Comment: If you're doing the *same* process in multiple model methods, you're doing something wrong. What are you doing that requires each method to do the same thing?

Comment: @Jon I have to request to a remote REST api. So a lot of methods will have setting request headers

Comment: That sounds like something that should be done in the controller. In general, anything that *changes an object itself* is done in the model, but anything that *performs an action* on an object is done in the controller. [See here](http://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/top-10-mistakes-that-rails-programmers-make#common-mistake-3-putting-too-much-logic-in-the-model)

Comment: what exactly are method1, method2, etc.'s relationship to each other?

Comment: @Jon So you recommend the 'request action' has to be in controller and after i get the response, delegate the db transaction to model? sounds like this is better :)

Comment: @Canna Exactly. It's a common mistake that people try to put everything in the model, but things like this are definite controller material.